# how to create tomcat app from java files on terminal

Tags: java, tomcat, terminal

I have some .java files and the unzipped tomcat folder and I have to build a single "install.sh" file to add the site to tomcat.

What I would do is:

1. create a dir in tomcat/webapps/myapp
2. copy the index.html file

But how do I install the .java files?

Note: this has to be highly portable, so I cannot rely on mvn or some other terminal tools.
After the ./install.sh I want to be able to run "bin/catalina.sh" and browse to localhost/myapp

Is this possible?

Comment: have you looked at tomcat tutorial (on official tomcat website)?

Comment: Compile your *.java and copy the *.class files to WEB-INF\classes folder. That can be achieve simply by javac and cp command.

Comment: yes I did. All they said is either using eclipse, or mvn or .war files ..

Comment: I copied over the *.class files to webapps/myproject/WEB-INF/classes/packages/.../. Then I created the web.xml file. Everything worked, but then it said it was missing the servlet implementation. In the end I just used the net.httpsserver from sun. 
Had this deadline so I had to figure out something.

Thank you all! 
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help you.

You need to have the tomcat and jdk:
[image]

1) You can create the jar file using:

```
jar cvf TicTacToe.jar TicTacToe.class audio images
```

(You can see more here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

2) Then, you just enter to tomcat's bin folder and do startup.sh

If you need to change some class after that, you can compile the classes you need and replace them in WEB-INF/classes folder inside webapps.

I hope this can help you.